# How do I use a controller for a template in the routing config?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular so please be kind to me if the terminology isn't quite right. I'm trying to build a simple website which currently consists of 3 pages with controllers for different pages in separate files.

I have routing setup and I want to use a controller on the contact page but I keep getting this error:

`Argument 'js/controllers/contact/ContactController.js' is not a function, got undefined`

I have an app.js file which looks like this:

```
angular.module('simpleApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home/index.html'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about/index.html'
      })
      .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contact/index.html',
        controller: 'js/controllers/contact/ContactController.js',
        controllerAs: 'contactCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

and this is my body in my main index.html:

```
<body ng-app="simpleApp">
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="/#/" class="logo">SimpleApp</a>
          </div>
          <nav class="main-menu" ng-controller="NavController as navCtrl">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
              <li>
                <a href="/#/" class="main-menu__link" ng-class="{ 'main-menu__link--active': navCtrl.isActive('/')}">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/#/about" class="main-menu__link" ng-class="{ 'main-menu__link--active': navCtrl.isActive('/about')}">about</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/#/contact" class="main-menu__link" ng-class="{ 'main-menu__link--active': navCtrl.isActive('/contact')}">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div ng-view></div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      footer
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/shared/NavController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/contact/ContactController.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I'm not sure what to do to fix this or what I'm doing wrong.

Really appreciate your help in advance

Comment: jsfiddle that beast!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything looks right to me but try changing the controller in the route 
from this:

```
controller: 'js/controllers/contact/ContactController.js',
```

to this:

```
 controller: 'ContactController',
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't fix it :(

Comment: @saunders look at edit..it should be controller name in `controller` options\

Comment: @PankajParkar yh you edited it before I could. Thanks!

Comment: @PankajParkar Thank you for your edit. That worked :). I will have to find some documentation to explain as i'm sure when i did codeschool it said that is the url of the controller. *I will accept answer when I can

Comment: @saunders it shouldn't be the url, it should be the name of the controller itself.

Answer (score 1):

In route file, under controller section you don't have to provide js reference , you just have to put controller name.

because once application initialized , angular know its all controller name . so you don't have to further provide reference anywhere. 
Always provide related reference to the start up file.

Answer (score 0):

not use Path of Controller File. just use name of Controller. like if your controller file-> *js/controllers/contact/ContactController.js*

```
app.controller("ContactController", contactControllerFun);
contactControllerFun.$inject = ['$scope',....];
function contactControllerFun($scope, ....)
{
   //your controller code.....
}
```

means
not **controller: 'js/controllers/contact/ContactController.js',** use "**controller: 'ContactController'**"

Comment: You have wrong concept about this..please update your answer..or refer the 1st answer..

Answer (score 0):

I geuss that the name of your controller is `NavController`  So please you have to change your route config like bellow:

```
.when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contact/index.html',
        controller: 'NavController',
        controllerAs: 'contactCtrl'
      })
```

because controller parameter accept the name of your controller and not the path of file.